# service.js detected as register but didn't execute

Tags: angular, npm

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-CD_5YhJTA) link for angular 2.0 tutorial.

I successfully displayed the list of courses but when I created the   AuthorComponent my app will not run anymore because of the following error:

```
Error: http://localhost:3000/app/components/author.service.js detected as       register but didn't execute.
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/components/author.service.js as "./author.service" from http://localhost:3000/app/components/author.component.js
at SystemJSLoader.<anonymous> (system.src.js:3261)
at SystemJSLoader.<anonymous> (system.src.js:3526)

at SystemJSLoader.<anonymous> (system.src.js:3774)
at SystemJSLoader.<anonymous> (system.src.js:4121)
at SystemJSLoader.instantiate (system.src.js:4357)
at system.src.js:333
at Zone.run (angular2-polyfills.js:1243)
at zoneBoundFn (angular2-polyfills.js:1220)
at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (angular2-polyfills.js:468)
at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (angular2-polyfills.js:480)
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CourseComponent} from './components/course.component';
import { AuthorComponent } from './components/author.component';


@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<h1>Test angular application</h1>
<course></course>    
<author></author>
`,
directives:[AuthorComponent,CourseComponent]
}) 
export class AppComponent { }
```

**CourseComponent**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { CourseService } from './../services/courses.service';
 @Component({
  selector:'course',
  template:`
  <h1>Courses component page</h1>
  {{ title }} 
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#course of courses">
    {{ course }}
    </li>
  </ul>    
  `,
  providers:[CourseService]
})

export class CourseComponent{
 title="List of Courses";
 courses;

 constructor(courseService:CourseService){
    this.courses=courseService.getCourses();
 }
}
```

**CourseService**

```
export class CourseService{
 getCourses():string[]{
    return ["Math","English","Science"];
 }
}
```

**AuthorComponent**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { AuthorService} from './../services/author.service';
 @Component({
 selector:'author',
 template:`
      <h3>List of Authors</h3> 
      {{title}}
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="author of authors">
    {{author}}
 </li>
</ul>
`,
 providers:[AuthorService]
 })


export class AuthorComponent{
 title="List of Authors";
 authors:string[];

 constructor(authorService:AuthorService){
    this.authors=authorService.getAuthors();
 }
}
```

**AuthorService**

```
export class AuthorService{

getAuthors():string[]{
    return ["Author01","Author02"];
}

}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
 "name": "angular_quickstart",
 "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
"start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"lite": "lite-server",
"typings": "typings",
"postinstall": "typings install" 
},  
  "license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
"systemjs": "0.19.22",
"es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
"es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
"zone.js": "0.5.15"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.1.0",
"typescript": "^1.7.5"
}
}
```

**Edit**
Editted for drug instead of course.

Answer (score 2):

My issue has been fixed.
Just opened the editor and found out that the pharmacy.service.ts file is still unsaved.

I don't know if this is the real cause of my issue.

Comment: I did the same thing, forgetting to save the service ts file.

Answer (score 0):

I see in the `Course` component, you have `drug` instead of `course`

```
template:`
  <h1>Courses component page</h1>
  {{ title }} 
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#course of courses">
    {{ course }}
    </li>
  </ul>    
  `,
```

Also in the `AuthorComponent`, you forgot to put `#` in the for loop

```
template:`
      <h3>List of Authors</h3> 
      {{title}}
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="#author of authors">
    {{author}}
 </li>
</ul>
`,
```

Comment: You can also do `<li *ngFor="let author of authors">{{author}}</li>`

Comment: Hi Tumen_t,
Thank you for your response 
I already changed my *ngFor but I still encoutered that error above

Answer (score 0):

your ngFor is wrong

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#course of courses">
    {{ drug }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

should be

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
     {{ course }}
    </li>
 </ul>
```

also you never defined `drug` so how would angular know?

Comment: Hi Mike, 
Thank you for your response,
I already changed the drug to course and remove # 
I can view the courses but when I include the authorscomponent in appcomponent I encountered the above error in my console.

Comment: @iamj get rid of the  directives line in app.component